# Consistency of the Subcomplete Forcing Axiom (relative to a supercompact cardinal)

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

In the introduction to his [Singapore lecture](http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~raesch/org/jensen/pdf/Singapore_Lectures_final_version.pdf) Jensen mentions that the Subcomplete Forcing Axiom is consistent relative to a supercompact cardinal.

Can anyone refer me to a proof of this claim?

Comment: This is the standard argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jensen outlines the proof on page 65 of the notes you refer to (Theorem 5). It's the standard argument.